# How To rsync Entire Disk To Create Complete VPS Back Up

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, backup, snapshot

I'm working on creating a snapshot of my entire vps, including all settings and directories - everything.

I would like to download the backup from my remote vps machine to my local computer. I found a code online:

`rsync -auHxv –numeric-ids`

However, I'm not sure how to make this work on the remote server and download to my computer. Also, I'm new to `rsync` so if you see room for improvement, your insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-x` skips things. Do it from a rescue system or use bind mounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` is usually used via `ssh` like this:

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh hosting:<PATH> .
```

`-e ssh` can be omitted because `ssh` is the default:

```
$ rsync -avz hosting:<PATH> .
```

where `hosting` is `ssh` alias for your `VPS` server. You can also use an explicit IP address and username. Next time the same command will run only new files will be downloaded.

- `-a` means archive mode - copy directory recursively and recreate symlinks, save permissions, modification times, groups ownerhsip, owners
- `-v` means verbose
- `-z` means compress

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying it out :-) For the output, do I have to specify an extension? `rsync -avz root@host:<PATH> /path/to/output.gz` or something like that?

Comment: `rsync` does not generate tarball or anything like that but recreates remote directory structure. In my example I used `.` to make rsync work in a current directory.

Comment: Might be worth including `--delete` depending on your use case, otherwise the destination may accumulate a lot of old cruft.